# How to fetch data from Database table by using MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

Currently, I'm stuck here in this part of my program. I want to fetch the data from the table I created which named enrollment_confirm. I want to add the total of female students and male students then the total combined of the two gender.

Here is my code so far in MySQL.

```
include_once('samplesf1-db.php');
$pdo = Database::connect();
$query1 = "SELECT 
               COUNT(CASE WHEN UPPER(Gender) = 'TOTAL MALE' THEN 1 END) Male,
               COUNT(CASE WHEN UPPER(Gender) = 'TOTAL FEMALE' THEN 1 END) Female,
               COUNT(CASE WHEN Gender IS NULL THEN 1 END) 'Not Assigned',COUNT(LRN) AS 'COMBINED'  FROM enrollment_confirm";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query1);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
echo $row['Gender'];
    }
  
Database::disconnect();
?>
```

Is there anything

So, when I run the code. This is what it says.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01BGo.png)

Can you tell me if I did something wrong in the query?

Comment: Your query result returns Male,Femal and COMBINED, you can do not have gender in your result. that is why you are getting this error? you echo "Males = $row['Female']";

Comment: Knowing the table schema would be useful

Comment: The error message however is easy to diagnose. You do not have a field / column in the returned recordset called `Gender` so when you call `echo $row['Gender'];` it will never be found